# relative liquid links fail on github pages

Tags: ruby, github, jekyll, liquid

i'm fairly new to jekyll and github in general, so i apologize for my dumb mistakes, but i'm trying to rebuild my personal site through GitHub pages, and will eventually use a custom domain name. i've found a few threads discussing similar issues, but no solid solutions that i could find.

locally, everything works fine. but on Pages,

```
 <a href='{{site.baseurl}}{{item.url}}'>
```

points to ryantroyford.io/page.html, instead of ryantroyford.io/project/page.html. as such, all my images and links are dead.

[here](https://github.com/ryantroyford/ryantroyford.com) is a link to the repo. [an issue](https://github.com/mojombo/jekyll/issues/332) has been tracked on GH, but i didn't see any resolution that i could understand.

thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Have you tried using the HTML `base` tag (cf. http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp) ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the html `<base>` tag, [check it out](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_standardattributes.asp).

Basically you add this to your default layout

```
<base href="/PROJECT_NAME/">
```

and have all your local links relative to the project's root folder.